# Does reducing the scale of an object in three.js have a negative impact on performance?

Tags: three.js

I have a scene with a couple of rendered objects.  I wanted to render them all with real world dimensions.  When I first loaded them, they all appeared huge so I scaled them down to x0.02.

As I add more post-processing (lighting, shadows, shaders etc) to the scene, the performance is really getting hit.

At this stage, I'm wondering if it's because I have scaled down the objects by a factor 50.

If I load them into the scene without any scaling, is this likely to help my FPS rate?

(I've tried but so far this doesn't seem to have any effect).

Comment: It's because of post processing. Scaling won't make any difference unless objects are too big for camera

Comment: I think that's the problem then.  I haven't figured out to move the camera far enough away so I hacked it a bit by scaling them down.  Back to the manual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.
The scaling of the models will impact the loading speed since all the positions of the vectors have to be adjusted.
But after the object is loaded and placed into memory it shouldn't have any impact.
However, it is good practice to scale your models in 3d editing software instead of scaling during loading.

edit:
Also, you might want to check how many polygons your model has.
Lots of models have more polygons than they really need. More polygons == less performance.
you can use software packages to decimate the number of polygons in your model.